# Trying to create a regex in PHP that matches patterns inside a pattern

Tags: php, regex

I have seen some regex examples where the string is "Test string: Group1Group2", and using preg_match_all(), matching for patterns of text that exists inside the  tags.

However, what I am trying to do is a bit different, where my string is something like this:

"some t3xt../s8fo=123,sij(variable1=123,variable2=743,variable3=535)"

What I want to do is match the sections such as 'variable=123' that exist inside the parenthesis.

What I have so far is this:

```
if( preg_match_all("/\(([^\)]*?)\)"), $string_value, $matches )
{
   print_r( $matches[1] );
}
```

But this just captures everything that's inside the parenthesis, and doesn't match anything else.

Edit:
The desired output would be:

```
   "variable1=123"
   "variable2=743"
   "variable3=535"
```

The output that I am getting is:

```
   "variable1=123,variable2=743,variable3=535"
```

Comment: I think you are contradicting yourself or need more explanation.  _match the sections such as 'variable=123' that exist inside the parenthesis_ is the same as _But this just captures everything that's inside the parenthesis_.  What output do you want?

Comment: Just use `preg_match` and then `explode(',', $matches[1])` or current code and loop matches and explode.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I edited the post with extra explanation.

Comment: @AbraCadaver yeah, I was thinking of using a preg_match then inside doing a preg_match_all to get all of the matches... but I thought if there was a one liner, that'd be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the matches you need with a single call to `preg_match_all` if the matches do not contain `(`, `)` or `,`:

```php
$s = '"some t3xt../s8fo=123,sij(variable1=123,variable2=743,variable3=535)"';
if (preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!\A),|\()\K[^,]+(?=[^()]*\))~', $s, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1QdY9r/1) and a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/VCDZH).

*Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!\A),|\()` - either end of the preceding successful match and a comma, or a `(` char
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards all text matched so far from the current overall match memory buffer
- `[^,]+` - one or more chars other than a comma (use `[^,]*` if you expect empty matches, too)
- `(?=[^()]*\))` - a positive lookahead that requires zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)` immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: I wouldn't even attempt it but figured you would be along with a pattern :-)

Comment: Yeah, this worked perfectly, even when I used this string:

"00000(000000)000(var1=123,var2=123)

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
preg_match("/\(([^\)]+)\)/", $string_value, $matches);
$result = explode(",", $matches[1]);
```

If your end result is an array of key => value then you can transform it into a query string:

```
preg_match("/\(([^\)]+)\)/", $string_value, $matches);
parse_str(str_replace(',', '&', $matches[1]), $result);
```

Which yields:

```
Array
(
    [variable1] => 123
    [variable2] => 743
    [variable3] => 535
)
```

Or replace with a newline `\n` and use [parse_ini_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php).

Comment: That's great! Thanks for your suggestion, I will try doing the 1st option. But seeing all these examples makes be understand regex much better.

Comment: Hey, another question. How would you work with a string that is like this:

"234234(343434)34234(variable1=123,variable2=123,variable3=123)"

How can you match the pattern were there are parenthesis, and inside the parenthesis there must be a pattern of 1 or more "variable=123"?

In the above string, there is substring "(343434)" and this shouldn't match this scenario.

Comment: Ask the other guy ;-)  He can regex anything.